# What is the meaning of count argument in str_replace function of php? How to use it?

Tags: str-replace

I would like to know what is the meaning of count argument in `str_replace()` function of PHP. This argument is optional. We have to pass it through reference. But why? What is it for? How can I use it?
Syntax of `str_replace()`:

`str_replace(searchValue, replaceValue, String, [&count]);`

Refenrence: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Thank you.

Comment: Seriously …? The description of the parameter already explains it, and there is even an example further down the page.

Comment: But how to use it? Can you give any simple example?

Comment: The example is already there, on the page you yourself linked to! The last one in the section “Example #1 Basic str_replace() examples” …

Comment: Yeah! Got it. Thanks.